# C Is there a way to get the type of the return type of a function without calling the function?

Tags: c, typeof

I want to use the typeof operator to declare a variable that will hold the return value of a function.

```
int func(void) {
  ++counter; 
}

typeof(func()) val = func(); // side effects for calling func() twice
```

Is there a way I can use typeof on a function to get the return type without calling the function?

Solution: My bad. There is no side effect.

Comment: ´typeof` is not a standard operator (yet). Please state which toolchain you use, what you tried and how this did not succeed.

Comment: `side effects for calling func() twice` I do not understand that part. Did you run the executable? Could you show an [MCVE] where the `func()` is called twice? The `typeof` that __is available__ in gcc compiler does __not__ evaluate the argument. I wonder - what compiler do you use? Is there a `typeof` implementation in C that does call the function? Can you show it?

Comment: My bad. When I tried it, I thought there was a side effect. It doesn't seem to have a side effect when I tried it again.. I must have made a mistake in my first test. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html), the GCC `typeof` extension does not evaluate the operand unless it has a variably modified type (a type that is a variable length array type or is derived from one).

You can also use the extension `__auto_type` to define an object whose type is determined from its initializer, and this avoids evaluation for variably modified types as well:

```
__auto_type val = func();
```

Answer (score 3):

Not in standard C, but GCC and clang provide the `__typeof__` extension which does what you want.